# How to keep toggle icon on far right while using buttons in panel, PrimeNg

Tags: css, primeng

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-wgqsvt)

I am using a toggleable panel with PrimeNg, and I am looking to place a button, right justified, but to the left of the toggle icon. So far, I have the following in my html:

```
<p-panel
  header="Testing Toggle"
  [style]="{ width: '100%' }"
  [collapsed]="collapsed"
  [toggleable]="true">
<p-header>
  <button
    pButton
    label="Clear"
    icon="pi pi-refresh"
    class="ui-button-warning"
    style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;">
  </button>
</p-header>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
  Itaque nisi iste praesentium, voluptatibus nam facere omnis
  deleniti natus pariatur sed officiis minus illum harum ad beatae alias. 
  Consequuntur, debitis atque.
</p-panel>
```

As expected, using the `float: right` on the button, the button goes all the way to the right in the header, forcing the toggle icon to the left:

[image]

Is there a way to use this button or the `ui-panel-titlebar-toggler` class to keep the toggle icon on the far right, and have the buttons to the left of it?

I have also tried using the `.ui-panel-titlebar-toggler` with a `float: right` property, hoping it would push all the way over, but this did not change anything.

Comment: Added answer @JeremyLucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-hxpmbm

You have to give `margin-right` in percentage to make it for all resolution. Whichever element need right most give negative `margin-right`.

```
.ui-panel .ui-panel-titlebar-icon{
    width: 6%!important;
    margin-right: -26%!important;
    margin-top: 6px!important;
}
```

this you have to add in `styles.css`

and

```
<button
    pButton
    label="Clear"
    icon="pi pi-refresh"
    class="ui-button-warning"
    style="float: right;margin-right: 7%;width:16%"
  >
  </button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this solved the issue well enough